# Running Java from the windows command line

Tags: java

I recently asked a bout a java program I could not find the start point to and was told to look in the bat file which started it but I do not understand what it says.

This program runs on a tomcat server and must be running before the .jsp pages will run so they are not the starting point.

Can anyone explain what this means and where the program starts so I can do a step through.

```
D:\foo_development\server>java -Xmx256M -Djava.library.path=lib -Djava.rmi.serv
er.hostname=192.168.0.104 -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:\foo_development\
server\foo_server.jar http://192.168.0.104:8000/foo_client_stubs/server_keycon
sole_stubs.jar" -Djava.security.policy=conf/java.policy -jar foo_server.jar 109
8 2001
```

This is exactly how it appears in the cmd window after I click run.bat

Comment: for the future - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Comment: @MByD: for the future:  please link to a *current* version ;-) http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: @Joachim - every time I don't look at the number I get the old docs... Google! please start giving links to the new API!

Comment: @MByD: I know and it annoys me as well. Appending "/6" to the search terms *usually* helps. Other than that: if we make sure to link to current versions, Google should start picking that up as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze the command line:

- `java`: the executable
- `-Xmx256M`: how much memory to use
- `-Djava.library.path=lib` where to find native libraries (for JNI)
- `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.104 -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:\foo_development\
  server\foo_server.jar http://192.168.0.104:8000/foo_client_stubs/server_keycon
  sole_stubs.jar"` RMI related stuff
- `-Djava.security.policy=conf/java.policy` which security policy to use
- `-jar foo_server.jar` the JAR file to execute! **This** is the juicy bit!
- `109 8 2001` arguments passed to your `main()` method

So `foo_server.jar` is the .jar file that gets executed. Check its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` for a line that starts with `Main-Class:` and that should tell you which class gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
D:\foo_development\server>java -Xmx256M -Djava.library.path=lib -Djava.rmi.serv
er.hostname=192.168.0.104 -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="file:/D:\foo_development\
server\foo_server.jar http://192.168.0.104:8000/foo_client_stubs/server_keycon
sole_stubs.jar" -Djava.security.policy=conf/java.policy -jar foo_server.jar 109
8 2001
```

This command runs foo_server.jar file with arguments 109,8,201. And all other before -jar are vm arguments to tell jvm about the different memory size like heapmemory size and aslo library path.

For your main class you will find its entry in MANIFIST file as `Main-class:-- foo.bar.MainClass`

Answer (score 1):

In short you have

```
java -jar foo_server.jar
```

The rest is just configuration and arguments.

In the foo_server.jar there will be a MANIFEST.MF file which contains a line like

```
Main-Class: com.mycompany.foo.FooMain
```

This is the class where `main(String[])` is called when it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the command:

- `java` is the executable to run (`java.exe`, found on the path)
- `-Xmx256M` specifies a maximum heap size of 256 megabytes
- `-D` (multiple times) defines various Java system properties
- `-jar` means "load the given jar file, and start with the class specified by the `Main-Class` attribute in its manifest
- `foo_server.jar` is the jar file to load
- `1098 2001` are the command line arguments to `main` (so `args` will be an array with elements "1098" and "2001"

Answer (score 1):

The key part is the options `-jar foo_server.jar`. This tells the JRE to open that named JAR, to read the `Main-Class` property from its metadata (in the archive's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) and execute that (starting from its static `main` method, as normal).

Answer (score 1):

The main class of an jar can be specified in the manifest of this jar. (@see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

In your case it is the `foo_server.jar`.  This jar (a jar it is just a zip) must have a folder `META-INF` where the manifest is located.